# Does SQL Server execute a CTE expression if it is not used?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to debug a query that is performing slowly. It has several `with` expressions which are `left joined`. When I remove the joins, it speeds up considerably.

Original query:

```
;with CTE as
(
    Select * 
    from table1
)  
SELECT * 
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN CTE ON table2.CTEID
```

Better performing query:

```
;with CTE as
(
     Select * 
     from table1
) 
SELECT * 
FROM table2
```

In the above, does it not execute CTE since it is not joined, or does it execute it regardless?

Comment: How about the actual query? With nothing but a word puzzle we can't do much to help. And "with" is how you define a common table expression. It is not a variable.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm confused. When you use with, does it actually perform the query inside the expression top down, or does it perform it when it is called?

Comment: It is an inline view, it isn't called. It is part of the query.

Comment: You might want to read up on ctes as you seem to be confused about what they are and how they work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx Here is another great article on the topic. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Comment: Well one query has a join and one doesn't. Why would you expect the first NOT to take longer?

Comment: The cte is always executed. Your performance problem is likely related but without any details we can't really help.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, that's what I was wondering. I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: So the real issue of your question is that your query was too slow. Do you still need help with that?

Comment: Well it is still slow but I don't feel like I have good enough information to ask a specific question about it yet. It's quite large and I'm trying to narrow down the problem before I ask for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is probably not-- the query optimizer is pretty smart about not executing unnecessary stuff.  Every query is different, and the query optimizer uses statistics about your actual data to decide how to evaluate it, so the only way to know for sure, is to get SQL Server to tell you how it evaluated your query.

To do this, execute your query in SQL Server Management Studio with 'Include Actual Execution Plan' and you will be see clearly how it evaluated the query.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the execution plan. And you were correct. Contra Sean's comment it did NOT execute the CTE.

Comment: Well I guess defining a cte and not using it would be completely absurd but it would make sense that it doesn't select the data because it was never selected.

Comment: Right well I wanted to understand if it was the CTE or the join that was causing the bottleneck. And while I know now it's the join in my particular case (running the contents of the CTE alone performs well), I wanted to better understand what was happening.